# Couldn't the comment vote rate limitation be made more ergonomic?

Tags: discussion, comments

Quite often I read a comment thread, and then decide which comments I vote up.
As soon as this is more than one comment, I get an error message
that I can cast only one comment vote every 5 seconds. -- This happens quite
frequently, while I don't remember ever having hit any other rate limitation
of the site.

I think comment votes are quite useful to quickly find the important comments,
and are rather used too little than too much.
So wouldn't it be possible to make the comment vote rate limitation a bit more ergonomic, e.g.
by setting only a maximum number of comment votes per minute, per hour or per day? --
Say, hitting a limit like 6 per minute or 60 per hour would already be much less likely.

**Update (August 18, 2014):** Now after two weeks, the score of this post
suggests considerable interest in the matter, but nobody proposed anything concrete.
Therefore let me make a few concrete proposals for polling -- see below.
Vote up every proposal you support, and vote down every proposal you are against.
Also feel free to add more alternatives. Depending on the outcome of this poll,
I will make a concrete feature proposal.

**Update (August 23, 2014):** I just noticed that now the one-per-5-seconds-throttle for
comment votes has been removed, as announced [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/382/can-we-get-x-comment-votes-per-y-minutes-rather-than-one-vote-per-5-seconds/238331#238331) two days ago. I thus think
the main objective of this post has been reached, independent of this post.
Unless people think otherwise and wish further changes, I therefore consider this case
as closed.

Comment: I have added the tags feature-request, which seems to apply here. Hope you don't mind. I completely agree with what you say.

Comment: @Joël it seems you did  in fact not apply the tag. But actually it is better you did not. A feature request should be something more specific (it is a considerable difference to have this per minute or per day). The standard procedure is  to first start a discussion, the result of the discussion *then* might be a precise feature request, or dropping the matter or still something else.

Comment: There is the same problem with deleting comments.

Comment: An equally inconvenient feature is the "have all your second thoughts within the next 5 minutes"-rule (the time window when you can still edit).

Comment: @bof it is even in a literal sense  part of this very problem. Deleting a comment is technically casting a (different type of) vote on a comment but it counts as comment vote.

Comment: @ChristianRemling that one was discussed repeatedly see http://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/1628/about-the-option-of-editing-comments-a-different-algorithm and http://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/1719/interpretation-of-time-limit-for-editing-comments for example.

Comment: It seems that they have removed this limit entirely (but kept the 30 comment votes per day limit), see [this MSE answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/238331).

Comment: @LoganMaingi: Ah, I see ... interesting! -- Though you should rather say: they *will* remove this limit, as it hasn't been done so far. In any case, if this change is done SE-wide, my post is redundant and no longer needed. Though, the remaining limit of 30 comment votes per day is not very high as well, I think.

Comment: Oh yikes. It's been a year already???

Answer (score 21):

The comment vote rate limitation should be changed to 10 comments per minute.
Vote up if you support this alternative, and vote down if you are against.

Answer (score 1):

The comment vote rate limitation should be left as it is, i.e. nothing should be changed.
Vote up if you support this alternative, and vote down if you are against.

Answer (score -4):

The comment vote rate limitation should be changed to one comment vote every second.

Comment: Note that this is an old thread from last year; if you would like to propose further changes, I think it would be helpful if you would say a bit more, rather than just adding another alternative to an old poll.

Answer (score -5):

The comment vote rate limitation should be changed to 100 comments per hour.
Vote up if you support this alternative, and vote down if you are against.

Answer (score -8):

The comment vote rate limitation should be changed to 1000 comments per UTC day.
Vote up if you support this alternative, and vote down if you are against.